# setAttribute for multi-level <div> separately

Tags: javascript, html

I want a professional code for auto looping inside the `<li>` tag and `setAttribute` data-level for each level `<div>` dynamicly. for example if we have  more than 10 level works properly.

I following this codes:

```js
var subMenuLevelOne = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-menu > ul > li > div');
var subMenuLevelTwo = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-menu > ul > li > div > ul > li > div');
var subMenuLevelThree = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-menu > ul > li > div > ul > li > div > ul > li > div');
var subMenuLevelFour = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-menu > ul > li > div > ul > li > div > ul > li > div > ul > li > div');
var navMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');
for(var i=0;i<subMenuLevelOne.length;i++) {
 subMenuLevelOne[i].setAttribute("data-level", 1);
}
for(var i=0;i<subMenuLevelTwo.length;i++) {
 subMenuLevelTwo[i].setAttribute("data-level", 2);
}
for(var i=0;i<subMenuLevelThree.length;i++) {
 subMenuLevelThree[i].setAttribute("data-level", 3);
}
for(var i=0;i<subMenuLevelFour.length;i++) {
 subMenuLevelFour[i].setAttribute("data-level", 4);
}

console.log(subMenuLevelOne);
console.log(subMenuLevelTwo);
console.log(subMenuLevelThree);
console.log(subMenuLevelFour);
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
   <div class="sub-menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">menu 1-1</a>
    <div class="sub-menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">menu 1-1-1</a>
     <div class="sub-menu">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">menu 1-1-1-1</a>
      <div class="sub-menu">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">menu 1-1-1-1-1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">menu 1-1-1-1-2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">menu 1-1-1-1-3</a></li>
       </ul>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 1-1-1-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 1-1-1-3</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">menu 1-1-2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">menu 1-1-3</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menu 1-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu 1-3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu 1-4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu 1-5</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
   </li>
    
   <li><a href="#">menu 2</a>
   <div class="sub-menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">menu 2-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu 2-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu 2-3</a>
     <div class="sub-menu">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">menu 2-3-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 2-3-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 2-3-3</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">menu 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">menu 5</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why to use extra divs for submenus, `ul` elements are already defining the submenus in the structure. If you want to create the pro code by yourself, see some tips at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: @Teemu i want to style div separately with data-level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
function level(parent, element, tagName) {
    return (!element.parentNode || element.parentNode === parent) ? 0 :
      (element.tagName === tagName ? 1 : 0) + level(parent, element.parentNode, tagName);
}

const menuParent = document.querySelector('div.nav-menu');

menuParent.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
    div.setAttribute("data-level", level(menuParent, div, "DIV"));
});
```

I suggest that you roll up your own version; this isn't the pinnacle of elegance (but it's concise).

## Reader's digest version

I rewrote this into a more approachable version. Hope this helps you forward!

```
/* Note that this is a recursive function */
function level(parent, element, tagName) {

  /* We are at top level element, return 0 */
  if (!element.parentNode) {
    return 0;
  }

  /* We have reaced the predestined parent, return 0 */
  if (element.parentNode === parent) {
    return 0;
  }

  /* If this element matches the tag name, return 1 + results for all the parents */
  if (element.tagName === tagName) {
    return 1 + level(parent, element.parentNode, tagName);
  }

  /* Otherwise, just return results for all the parents */
  return level(parent, element.parentNode, tagName);
}

/* Find the root element for the menu tree */
const menuParent = document.querySelector('div.nav-menu');

/* Enumerate every <div> under the root element (at *every* level) */
const eachDivUnderParent = menuParent.querySelectorAll('div');

/* Iterate each <div> under <div class="nav-menu"> */
eachDivUnderParent.forEach(divElement => {
  /* Calculate the level at that element */
  const divLevel = level(menuParent, divElement, "DIV");
  /* Set the calculated value as `data-level` attribute */
  divElement.setAttribute("data-level", divLevel);
});
```

Comment: Special thanks Sami, your code works perfectly. I'm a beginner and I didn't understand your solution, please edit your code and add command. another question which website learn javascript perfectly?